# Problema com Rota no Angular acessada diretamente

Tags: angular, iis, angular-routes

Publiquei o projeto do Angular em uma máquina com o IIS, porém quando tento acessar o link com uma rota diretamente apresenta erro 404, exemplo "http://meusite.com/appiis/login" mas se acesso a url "http://meusite.com/appiis/" ele carrega normalmente, e se não está logado no sistema redireciona corretamente para login, consigo navegar em qualquer rota normalmente pelo angular, porém o problema só ocorre quando vou fazer diretamente pelo navegador.
Existe alguma configuração no IIS ou Angular que permita acessar as rotas diretamente pelo navegador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentacao](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) vc tem que reescrever um arquivo.

Tenta reesecrever o arquivo  web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar, obrigado pelo norte, com o auxílio de tutorial https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/06/14/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/ consegui resolver o problema